# How to add coloured blocks beneath x-axis in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to recreate a boxplot however I am having difficulty adding the coloured blocks beneath the x-axis as shown in this partial screenshot below

[image]

My code for this particular graph is as follows:

```
p_lymph <- ggplot(filtered_lymph, aes(x = cluster, y = `total cells`, fill = New_Condition, color = New_Condition)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), size = 0.9,linetype="solid", outlier.shape=NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=fill_colors) + #These two lines I am changing the legend label from New_Condition (as it is named in the original data column) to Treatment as stated on the original paper
  scale_color_manual(name="Condition", values = outline_colors) +
  theme_minimal()+
  guides(fill="none",color="none")+ #removing the legend
  labs(y="Total cells (%)",
       x="Lymphoid")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=x_lym_labels)+
  theme(
    axis.line=element_line(color="black",linewidth=0.5,linetype="solid"), #adding axis lines
    axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,vjust=1,hjust=1), #adjusting the angle of the x axis labels in line with the paper
    axis.ticks.x=element_line(colour="black",linewidth=0.5),#manually adding in tick breaks
    axis.ticks.y=element_line(colour="black", linewidth=0.5),
    panel.grid=element_blank() #removing grid lines
  )+
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,25, by=5),
                         limits=c(0,25), #Adjusting the y-axis breaks
                         labels=c("0","5","10","15","20","25") #customising the y-axis labels
                         )
  


print(p_lymph)
```

```
#the structure of this data frame is also as follows:

> str(filtered_lymph)
tibble [108 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ cluster          : chr [1:108] "CD4+ Tcells" "CD4+ Tcells" "CD4+ Tcells" "CD4+ Tcells" ...
 $ condition        : chr [1:108] "B16_NTX_1" "B16_NTX_2" "B16_NTX_3" "B16_NTX_4" ...
 $ total cells      : num [1:108] 1.706 1.415 2.01 0.858 1.264 ...
 $ New_Condition    : Factor w/ 3 levels "NTX","Anti-PD-1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ Tissue_Expression: chr [1:108] "Lymphoid" "Lymphoid" "Lymphoid" "Lymphoid" ...
```

I have found a couple articles online with similar block positioning but can't figure out how to relate my code to the suggested answers!

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not natively possible in ggplot. There are a few workarounds, however. I think the least hacky is to make a second plot of height-1 bars that you add in below the main plot using `patchwork`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(filtered_lymph, 
             aes(cluster, `total cells`, color = New_condition)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = after_scale(alpha(color, 0.3))), width = 0.6,
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),
               linewidth = 0.9, outlier.shape = NA) +
  scale_color_manual("Condition", values = c("#4d4b4c", "#4c517b", "#c63a41")) +
  ylim(0, 20) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(filtered_lymph, aes(cluster, 1, fill = cluster)) +
  geom_col(width = 1, position = "identity", color = "#00000020") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#8d0e13", "#e51d2f", "#f5e0e0", "#e67770"),
                    guide = "none") +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 16),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())

p1 + p2 + plot_layout(ncol = 1, nrow = 2, heights = c(20, 1))
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

Obviously, we don't have your actual data set (the output of `dput(filtered_lymph)` is much more useful than the output of `str(filtered_lymph)`). To demonstrate the above code, I generated a similar data set with the same names as yours as follows:

```r
set.seed(1)

filtered_lymph <- data.frame(
  cluster = rep(c("CD4+ T Cells", "Effector T Cells", "NK Cells",
                  "Progenitor T Cells"), each = 30),
  New_condition = rep(rep(c("NTX", "Anti-PD-1", "Anti-CTLA-4"), each = 10), 4),
  `total cells` = rnorm(120, 3, 0.5)^2, check.names = FALSE)

filtered_lymph[1:2] <- lapply(filtered_lymph[1:2], \(x) factor(x, unique(x)))
```