# Adding a square bracket under x-axis to group variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a square bracket outside of my plot - it should be placed beneath the x-axis and grouping the variables. I have included a screenshot of what I am attempting to recreate.

[image]

So far, pBrackets, as shown in this link:  ([Adding square brackets to group axis labels in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66603462/adding-square-brackets-to-group-axis-labels-in-ggplot2?rq=3)) has been the closest I have seen so far, however I am having trouble with selecting the correct co-ordinates.

I know there is also the geom_bracket function in ggplot - again I have tried to use this but struggled to get it to work.

If anyone has any simpler suggestions it would be much appreciated!

Please see below the code for my plot:

```
p_lymph <- ggplot(filtered_lymph, aes(x = cluster, y = `total cells`, fill = New_Condition, color = New_Condition)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), size = 0.9,linetype="solid", outlier.shape=NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=fill_colors) + #These two lines I am changing the legend label from New_Condition (as it is named in the original data column) to Treatment as stated on the original paper
  scale_color_manual(name="Condition", values = outline_colors) +
  theme_minimal()+
  guides(fill="none",color="none")+ #removing the legend
  labs(y="Total cells (%)",
       x=NULL)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=x_lym_labels)+
  theme(
    axis.line=element_line(color="black",linewidth=0.5,linetype="solid"), #adding axis lines
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x=element_line(colour="black",linewidth=0.5),#manually adding in tick breaks
    axis.ticks.y=element_line(colour="black", linewidth=0.5),
    panel.grid=element_blank() #removing grid lines
  )+
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,25, by=5),
                         limits=c(0,25), #Adjusting the y-axis breaks
                         labels=c("0","5","10","15","20","25") #customising the y-axis labels
                        )

          
             


library(patchwork)
#In order to create the coloured blocks which run along the x-axis, I put out a question via stackoverflow and used the response to within this next block of code. The suggestion was to create a second plot which could be arranged below. The link to my question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77574633/how-to-add-coloured-blocks-beneath-x-axis-in-r
colblocks_lym <- ggplot(filtered_lymph, aes(cluster, 1, fill=cluster))+
  geom_col(width=1, position = "identity", colour="NA")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#8d0e13","#e51d2f","#f5e0e0", "#e67770"),
                    guide="none")+
  coord_cartesian(expand=FALSE)+
  theme_minimal()+
  labs(y=NULL,
       x="Lymphoid")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=x_lym_labels)+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1, vjust=1),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())


combined_p_lymph <- p_lymph + colblocks_lym + plot_layout(ncol=1, nrow=2, heights=c(20,1))
print(combined_p_lymph)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It will help us if you can [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(filtered_lymph)`, if that is not too large. You could also reduce the amount of code to the minimum required for the important parts of the plot, and show us what you tried using `geom_bracket`.

Comment: Do you only want to use ggplot or are you open to base approaches?

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to base R plotting approaches, which in some cases I find much simpler, you can easily do this using `segments` and `xpd = TRUE`.

```
boxplot(value ~ type, data = DF, xlab = NA)
  mtext(unique(DF$group), side = 1, padj = 6, at = c(2, 5))
  segments(x0 = c(0.75, 3.75), x1 = c(3.25, 6.25), y0 = -0.25, xpd = TRUE) # horizontal lines
  segments(x0 = c(0.75, 3.25, 3.75, 6.25), y0 = -0.25, y1 = -0.20, xpd = TRUE) # vertical lines
```

Plots:

[image]

This will of course take some tweaking with your real data, but here I am using these data:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 1000
DF <- data.frame(type = sample(LETTERS[1:6], n, replace = TRUE),
                 value = runif(n))
DF[DF$type %in% LETTERS[1:3], "group"] <- "Group 1"
DF[DF$type %in% LETTERS[4:6], "group"] <- "Group 2"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me - I was trying to refrain from changing my plot created in ggplot to a base r plot and thus could not use your suggestion within my ggplot code. That was my fault, I should have specified for ggplot compatible code! I appreciate your response however and I am sure someone else will find this useful. I was able to achieve the brackets by using the annotate() and coord_cartesian() functions

Comment: @krw13 glad you figured out a solution - you should post your solution as an answer if it worked for you!